# Android In App Billing V3: How do I track an item bought multiple times

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

I try to set up an in-game-shop, where the user is able to buy a specific item (f.e. boost) multiple times in a row (by re-ordering this item each time). The user is able to use and "consume" this boosts while he plays.

I have this boost-item registered in the googles dev-console as a "managed item".

The problem is now: After a first successfull transaction, the boost-item is transfered to the user. Directly after that, a second transaction is not possible, because of the tracking: Play Console knows, that this boost-item is already "owned" and has to be "consumed" by the user first.

I tried to "consume" the item directly after the first transaction and storing the bought/remaining amounts of boosts ingame. It works fine and it is possible to buy boost items multiple times in a row. But then the app looses its ability to restore bought but unused boost-items after app-deletion and -reinstall.

I'm not sure if I understand the docs fully. Are managed consumables designed to work this way, or are they only made for a "buy-own-consume-rebuy-circle"? If so, how can I implement the tracking of multiple bought items?

I hope made my point of view clear. Thanks in advance for anything, which points me to the right direction.

Comment: Once you consume the item, managing it is up to you.  So if you need to restore it after device reset, you have to store that stuff off of the device somewhere.  Something like Firebase maybe.

Comment: Thank you! This could be the solution I was looking for. I will give firebase a closer look.